# Auto import Facebook page photos as nodes for views display

Tags: views, feeds, social-network

I have some experience using feeds and views, and I've looked at a few modules designed to integrate Drupal with Facebook. But I'm unable to figure out how to set up an importer to automatically pull Facebook photos from a page and turn them into nodes. I'd also like to map three fields for views display: image, description and FB album title to Drupal taxonomy term.

Suggestions on how best to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

JSON parser did the trick with a feeds importer properly mapped. Once I figured out how to get the data from Facebook, it was really just a matter of configuring the importer properly with the right expressions. I was pleasantly surprised to find that I could get the data without any token because the data comes from a public page, rather than a private profile. The url structure: http://graph.facebook.com/[album id]/photos.